# Sending email with an attachment from the form not working

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I have been working on a website where i want to get the input type "file" from the **user**, and **email** the same to the admin using php.

My code is as follows:

html:

```
<form class="pure-form"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="resumeUpload.php" method="POST">
                                            <label for="resume_attachment">Upload your resume</label>
                                            <input type="file" class="pure-input-rounded" name="resume_attachment">
                                            <button type="submit" name="resume_send" class="mt-20 mb-20" value="1">Submit</button>
                                        </form>
```

php:

```
if($_POST['resume_send'] && isset($_FILES['resume_attachment'])) 
{ 

    //$from_email      = 'sender@abc.com'; //from mail, sender email addrress 
    $recipient_email = 'xyz@gmail.com'; //recipient email addrress 

    //Load POST data from HTML form 
    //$sender_name = $_POST["sender_name"] //sender name 
    //$reply_to_email = $_POST["sender_email"] //sender email, it will be used in "reply-to" header 
    //$subject     = 'New Resume' //subject for the email 
    //$message     = $_POST["message"] //body of the email 


    /*Always remember to validate the form fields like this 
    if(strlen($sender_name)<1) 
    { 
        die('Name is too short or empty!'); 
    } 
    */

    //Get uploaded file data using $_FILES array 
    $tmp_name = $_FILES['resume_file']['tmp_name']; // get the temporary file name of the file on the server 
    $name    = $_FILES['resume_file']['name']; // get the name of the file 
    $size    = $_FILES['resume_file']['size']; // get size of the file for size validation 
    $type    = $_FILES['resume_file']['type']; // get type of the file 
    $error   = $_FILES['resume_file']['error']; // get the error (if any) 

    //validate form field for attaching the file 
    if($file_error > 0) 
    { 
        die('Upload error or No files uploaded'); 
    } 

    //read from the uploaded file & base64_encode content 
    $handle = fopen($tmp_name, "r"); // set the file handle only for reading the file 
    $content = fread($handle, $size); // reading the file 
    fclose($handle);                 // close upon completion 

    $encoded_content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content)); 

    $boundary = md5("random"); // define boundary with a md5 hashed value 

    //header 
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; // Defining the MIME version 
    //$headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n"; // Sender Email 
    //$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$reply_to_email."\r\n"; // Email addrress to reach back 
    $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n"; // Defining Content-Type 
    $headers .= "boundary = $boundary\r\n"; //Defining the Boundary 

    //plain text 
    $body = "--$boundary\r\n"; 
    $body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
    $body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
    $body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message)); 

    //attachment 
    $body .= "--$boundary\r\n"; 
    $body .="Content-Type: $file_type; name=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
    $body .="Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$file_name."\r\n"; 
    $body .="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"; 
    $body .="X-Attachment-Id: ".rand(1000, 99999)."\r\n\r\n"; 
    $body .= $encoded_content; // Attaching the encoded file with email 

    $sentMailResult = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers); 

    if($sentMailResult ) 
    { 
    echo "File Sent Successfully."; 
    unlink($name); // delete the file after attachment sent. 
    } 
    else
    { 
    die("Sorry but the email could not be sent. 
                    Please go back and try again!"); 
    } 
} 
?>
```

I have used this code but could not accomplish the task.

Can anyone here find the error in my code, and give the correct way of doing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem seems to be in this line:

```
if($_POST['button'] && isset($_FILES['attachment']))
```

It has two problems:

First, `$_POST['button']` will always yield a false value as it is not set. For this to work, you need the html to change: `<button type="submit" class="mt-20 mb-20" name="button" value="1">Submit</button>`. That is: add a `name` and `value` attribute, and the value should [**not be something that results in `falsey`**](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

What do you intent with this check? If you just want to check that the request came in as `POST`, just skip this because the presence of `$_FILES` should be enough. There is no `$_GET` file upload.

Second, `isset($_FILES['attachment'])` is always false because in the HTML, this file upload name is `resume_file`, not `attachment`.

Only after solving these issues, you could continue with the mail-problems, if they exist.

To be clear: your mail code is never reached.

Comment: hi, i have tried the corrections u told me. I have edited my code above. But still im facing a problem, when i comment the $subject line my code is ruuning successfully displaying "File sent successfully" message but the mail is not getting received. can you hellp me with that

Comment: If you mean by the $subject-line the one with `$subject = 'New Resume'`: that will generate an error because it does not end with a semi-colom `;`. As for not receiving the mail: that can be for a million of reasons. [The manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php): "It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination." Do you receive mail sent from the same server if the mail is simpler? E.g. try `mail('your@address', 'test', 'test');` and see what happens.

Comment: hi, mail() function is working fine for another form in the same server. but this form its not working.

Comment: Try to start from a minimal _working_ code in your current script (e.g. leave out the attachment from the mail at first and use the simplest form of `mail()`) and see what does work. Then slowly add functionality, step by step, until it breaks. Read logs etc. and if you can't figure it out, ask a question. I recommend asking a _new_ question about that specific new problem (you probably made several changes to the code as compared to the code in this question and changing this question to cater for a new follow-up problem is bad practice here on SO).

Comment: do i need to have a seperate smtp server for this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use the PHPMailer API to send your mails with attachments.

Here is a tip :

- Ask the user to upload a file with an input type file
- Upload this file to your server
- Send the attachment with PHPMailer

  `$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');`

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: Could you please upload your code ? and did you import PHPMailer using composer?

Comment: yes, i have a composer.json file with code // "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0"

Comment: Sorry Victor D, but this answer does not solve the code issues found in the code presented.

Comment: @Martin Right you are and I am baffled as to my VLQ flag being disputed. Giving my head a serious shake.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner one of the down sides of democracy `:-(`

Comment: @Martin Oh, "duh-mah-cruh"... (I) see. Oh yeah, "that".

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner if you started a petition on Meta for you to take absolute control  of killing VLQ posts, I'd back you `:-D`. Just don't mark my posts `;-)`

Comment: can anyone please give me the solution?

Comment: @SubhamKotnala if it is still not working, have you tried applying some of my answer? That is: is the code that sends the mail actually reached? In the code that you have presented, no mail will be sent, not even if you use PHPMailer.